# Redirect domainA.com to sub.domainB.com

Tags: apache-2.2, domain-name-system, .htaccess, redirect

Just a short and easy question, I hope.
Currently, I've got a primary domain linked to my (virtual) hosting server.
I now have a second domain name which I would like to link to a specific subdomain, i.e.

domainB.com/X -> subdom.domainA.com/X

Preferably without having this redirect show up in the address bar.
Can this be achieved through DNS settings alone, or would it require me to add a .htaccess file in Domain A's root folder?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are talking about Addon Domains. With AD you can have:

domainA.com or anything.subdomainA.com/anything
working under domainA.domainB.com

but always showing domainA.com in the browser's address bar

correct me if I'm mistaken